# How to update page after AJAX file upload?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, upload

I'm trying to come up with a way to display a progress bar for file uploads to my site. So far I came up with the following:

HTML:

```
<form action="upload/files.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmUpload">
    <input type="file" name="upfile" id="idUpload">
    <input type="text" name="txtV1">
    <input type="text" name="txtV2">
    <input type="submit" value="Add File" name="btnAddFile" id="btnAddNew" onClick="return btnAddClkd();">
</form>
<div>Current Progress: <span id="idPerc"></span></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function btnAddClkd()
{
    var frm_obj = document.getElementById("frmUpload");
    if(frm_obj != undefined)
    {
        var ajaxOK = false;
        if(frm_obj.action)
        {
            try
            {
                var objFrm = document.forms['frmUpload'];
                if(objFrm != undefined)
                {
                    var fd = new FormData(objFrm);
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    if(xhr != undefined)
                    {
                        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
                        xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
                        xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
                        xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
                        xhr.open("POST", frm_obj.action);
                        xhr.send(fd);

                        ajaxOK = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                ajaxOK = false;
            }
        }

        if(!ajaxOK)
        {
            //Failed to send with ajax, use regular method
            frm_obj.submit();
        }

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

function uploadProgress(evt)
{
    var objPerc = document.getElementById('idPerc');
    if(objPerc != undefined)
    {
        if(evt.lengthComputable)
        {
            var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
            objPerc.innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + '%';
        }
        else
        {
            objPerc.innerHTML = "-";
        }
    }
}

function uploadComplete(evt)
{
    var objPerc = document.getElementById('idPerc');
    if(objPerc != undefined)
    {
        objPerc.innerHTML = "Done";
    }
}

function uploadFailed(evt)
{
    var objPerc = document.getElementById('idPerc');
    if(objPerc != undefined)
    {
        objPerc.innerHTML = "Failed";
    }
}

function uploadCanceled(evt)
{
    var objPerc = document.getElementById('idPerc');
    if(objPerc != undefined)
    {
        objPerc.innerHTML = "Canceled";
    }
}
```

This concept works for the progress bar while a large file is uploading, but when the upload is done, the web server (or `upload/files.php` page) returns the result as a generated HTML page. So my question is how to get that HTML to be displayed? (Currently my upload finishes and my message shows, `"Current Progress: Done"` and that's it.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the entire body of the page with the new content, then you could do:

Add this onreadystatechange handler before you send the request.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // request finished and response is ready
    if (xhr.readyState == 4)
        document.body.innerhtml(xhr.responseText);
}
```

Comment: Where would I get the `the_ajax_respone` from?

Comment: edited it into the answer, use `xhr.responseText`. Also put in the onreadystatechange, which is called when the readyState of the XMLHttpRequest object changes.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to get that `XMLHttpRequest` reference from my  `uploadComplete` handler?

Comment: I think that since it is an event listener that is attached to the object, you should be able to use `this` in your uploadComplete function to target the `XMLHttpRequest` object

Comment: Yeah, I got it. But, still, you know since the actual HTML includes `<html>` tag, I don't think `document.body.innerHTML` is what I need... because that doesn't do anything, i.e. the page doesn't change.

Comment: In that case, use `document.write(xhr.responseText)`

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure yet. It works on Chrome but hangs up the page on IE 11, so I have to hit F5 to reload it.