# Can I get current file upload progress without using XMLHttpRequest.send()?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I've found a way to [implement file upload progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311047/how-to-update-page-after-ajax-file-upload) using XMLHttpRequest. The issue with this is that once uploading is complete the server returns HTML page that I can't seem to reliably display from `XMLHttpRequest`.

I tried the following:

```
//xhr = XMLHttpRequest
document.write(xhr.responseText);
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

also this:

```
//xhr = XMLHttpRequest
document.open('text/html');
document.write(xhr.responseText);
document.close();
```

Both seems to work under latest Chrome and FF but hang up IE. In other words it's not really reliable.

So I was thinking if there's a way to get the current file upload progress without using `XMLHttpRequest.send()` by letting a "regular" HTML file upload to go through?